# How to rebuild all projects in solution?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010

I have 5 projects within a solution of Visual Studio 2010 (4 projects C++ and 1 project C#).

There are some projects which depend on other ones.

I have configured all output directories (.lib, .dll) correctly.

When I choose "rebuild solution" from the menu, there are some projects for which the build failed.

I get the following error message:

> Error 1 error FTK1011: could not create the new file tracking log file: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ServerWinForm\Obj\CL.read.1.tlog. The file exists. C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ServerWinForm\Common\FileTracker Error   7   error LNK1104: cannot open file '../Bin\x86\Debug\Common.lib' Error 9   The referenced assembly "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DVRServerWinForm\CPPWrapper../Bin/x86/Debug\CPP‌​Wrapper.dll" was not found. If this assembly is produced by another one of your projects, please make sure to build that project before building this one.

But when I right click and build one by one each project with the order as in "Project Build Order", then it builds successfully.

Could someone tell me why this might happen?

Answer (score 4):

You need to right click on your solution, select properties, and select "Project Dependencies" and configure each project that is dependent on other projects in your entire solution so that it builds the correct ones first.

Comment: It was configured ok Bod Delavan.
Note: When I right click and build one by one each project with the order as in "Project Build Order", then it builds successfully.

Comment: Are you doing some special pre or post build commands as part of your build process?

Comment: I dont know about this, can you show me more details? Thank you!

Comment: If you need to do external operations as part of what you are building of specific projects, then you might be doing this. But since you're not familiar, chances are, that you aren't doing this. However, you can right click on a specific project and then configure this as part of "Build Events".

Comment: Two things: Please read this link pertaining to the error you are hitting. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/cda2c0da-33ed-48c0-8e51-5b4666865d55. Secondly, are these projects all .NET applications or a mix of .NET and native C++ applications? If they are all .NET, can you make sure you have the same .NET framework specified for all of these. You can right click on each of the projects and make sure the target framework is the same for all of them.

Comment: Thanks, but it is difficult to control. is there any other way to solve my problem?

Comment: There are 3 project C++ without .NET and 2 rest one is .NET with the same version 4.0.

Comment: The link to the MSDN article had spoke a problem similar to what you are experiencing. I would recommend going down that path. But I understand not everything is possible. The last thing I would recommend that I would do myself would be to re-create a brand new blank solution and add your existing projects 1 at a time, then re-build all until you get the build errors. This will help you track down exactly what project is causing issues and hopefully narrow down your solution.

Comment: More Info: It will be success when I choose Build Solution (F7). But It will be failed when I choose Rebuild Solution (Ctrl + Alt + F7).